# Hibernate/Oracle Sequence not working

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate and an oracle DB to try and insert a automated ID into a table using a sequence. The sequence defiantly exists on database but hibernate doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Here is all the relevant information:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        ....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
        ....
    ... 12 more
```

I know it says "Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist" but I can access the sequence on the database:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Property(
  id INT,
  address VARCHAR2(50),
  town VARCHAR2(50),
    postCode VARCHAR2(50),
    purchasePrice INT
);
```

Sequence:

```
create sequence property_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nomaxvalue;
```

Mapping xml:

```
<class name="com.rental.model.property.Property" table="PROPERTY">
    <meta attribute="class-description"> This class contains the property detail. </meta>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator class="sequence"/>
    </id>
    <property name="address" column="ADDRESS" type="string" />
    <property name="town" column="TOWN" type="string" />
    <property name="postCode" column="POSTCODE" type="string" />
    <property name="purchasePrice" column="PURCHASEPRICE" type="integer" />
</class>
```

annotation:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="property_seq", sequenceName="property_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1) 
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="property_seq")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Is the sequence object created in the same schema as that of the user logged-in to the hibernate session?  If not, did you create a synonym and grant access to the sequence?

Comment: maybe try adding a public synonym on property_seq

Comment: The user used by Hibernate is the same as the user that created the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using xml AND `@Annotation` at the same time? Maybe xml definition wins against annotation and Hibernate is retriving default sequence instead of your `property_seq`.
Try remove xml mapping and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks Bellabax. I removed the xml totally and added in all other annotations and then changed my factory to:


   factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Property.class). buildSessionFactory();